# LCK_M_IX em base de dados SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Galera, estou com duas bases de clientes distintos em SQL Server 2008, e ambos utilizando o mesmo sistema, que utiliza BDE para conexão.

Tenho um aplicativo próprio **Scripter** para fazer consultas SQL nos bancos de dados.

#### Problema

Em ambas as bases, eu executo `select * from TABELA` pelo **Scripter** e tento entrar no sistema, consigo sem problemas.

Porém se executar `select * from TABELA order by COLUNA desc`, e tentar entrar no sistema, em uma base eu consigo entrar, e em outra não.

Estou usando o `sp_WhoIsActive` para tentar achar o problema, e identifiquei que em ambas as bases de dados, o `SELECT` fica `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO`.

Na base que não consigo entrar diz que o `SELECT` está bloqueando um `INSERT`.

[image: Select do sp_WhoIsActive]

#### Tentativas

Já tentei recriar indice, shirink da base de dados e nada. 
Comparei as bases, e ambas tem a mesma configuração.

#### Observações

- Identifiquei que a base de dados que gera o `lock`, o `tempdb_allocations` e `tempdb_current` estão zerados, será que tem algo a ver?
- Outra detalhe é que na base de dados que **não gera o lock**, o Space Available está grande, e na base de dados que **gera o lock** está quase 0 (zero) conforme imagens abaixo

Não gera lock
[image: Banco de dados que não gera o lock]

Gera lock
[image: Banco de dados que gera o lock]

#### Dúvida

O que pode fazer para identificar o motivo do erro?

#### Dados adicionais (20/02/2018 as 13:25)

Rodei o sp_lock e o resultado foi:

```
spid   dbid   ObjId       IndId  Type Resource                         Mode     Status
------ ------ ----------- ------ ---- -------------------------------- -------- ------
51     42     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
52     42     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
54     76     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
55     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
56     103    0           0      MD   5(1:0:0)                         Sch-S    GRANT
56     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624712                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624713                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624714                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624715                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624708                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624709                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624710                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624711                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624704                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624705                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624706                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624707                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624660                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624661                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624662                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624663                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624659                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   1      PAG  1:526026                         IS       GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624716                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624717                         S        GRANT
56     103    366624349   0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
57     103    366624349   0      TAB                                   IX       GRANT
57     103    366624349   6      PAG  1:624717                         IX       WAIT
57     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
57     103    366624349   1      KEY  (07680471601e)                   X        GRANT
57     103    366624349   2      KEY  (9d8e9d84975e)                   X        GRANT
57     103    366624349   3      KEY  (2fcebe7f747e)                   X        GRANT
57     103    366624349   1      PAG  1:927056                         IX       GRANT
57     103    366624349   2      PAG  1:573725                         IX       GRANT
57     103    1477580302  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
57     103    366624349   4      PAG  1:607421                         IX       GRANT
57     103    1938105945  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
57     103    366624349   3      PAG  1:582200                         IX       GRANT
57     103    366624349   4      KEY  (da0106a2694d)                   X        GRANT
57     103    366624349   5      PAG  1:617162                         IX       GRANT
57     103    0           0      MD   5(1:0:0)                         Sch-S    GRANT
57     103    366624349   5      KEY  (1d3df3b848ca)                   X        GRANT
58     76     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
59     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
60     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
61     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
62     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
63     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
66     42     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
66     1      1131151075  0      TAB                                   IS       GRANT
67     42     0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
70     103    0           0      DB                                    S        GRANT
```